# opening a page and then calling a JS function on it (without onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have a main page that has links to 3 other pages. These three pages then have 3-4 sections controlled by Css styling and functions.

I want to make "sub-links" on the main page that will open the respective page, and call the function to display that section. My plan is to create global variables for each of the sections. The link (on the main page) will change the respective global variable to "true". Then when the next page is opened, each section will have a function that evaluates the global variable for that section. A return of true (set by the main page) will call the function to display that section.

1. user clicks main page "sub-link"
2. sub-link function changes global variable to true.
3. second page opens.
4. "onload" function evaluates global variables for true value.
5. "onload" function calls section function to appropriate true value.

My question is, are there other ways to do this? I know you can link HTML to a part of a page, but I am trying to get to a part that exists *after* a function is called. Will the global set by the main page remain true when the new page evaluates it? If the main page (and the sub-link function) closes, will it affect the second page or the global var?

Comment: you should use url fragments, and inspect `location.hash` onload on the 2nd page to determine which function to fire. or use localStorage since regular global variables will not work.

Comment: perhaps then I could use the HTML to jump to a *part* of a page... containing the function? Any chance I could establish these *parts* and keep them from firing off until that *part* is called specifically?

Answer (score 0):

simply use the

```
ajax.load('#someid',$('#someid').data('url'))
```

and add a div with data and that id

```
<div data-url="somepagehere.html" id="someid"><div>
```

now when you will call the ajax in your javascript . this result of that somepagehere.html will be shown in the div with id someid

Comment: I am trying to call a function that exists *after* an onclick event in the target page... perhaps a way to open the new page and trigger that specific onclink event?